# Cómo mostrar los últimos artículos por categoría en los bloques de Gutenberg (WP)

Tags: php, wordpress

Llevo unos días intentando averiguar la forma de mostrar los últimos artículos por categoría (que sea la misma que la del propio post) en un bloque de Gutenberg. Todos los tutoriales que he visto son sobre mostrar los últimos artículos en el loop, o simplemente muestran un artículos de una categoría específica. En este caso, necesitaría mostrar los artículos de la misma categoría que los posts (de forma dinámica).

He probado este código:

```
function Last5posts()   {
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category_name' => 'uncategorized');                  
    $last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) : 
        $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
        $link = get_permalink();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $date = get_the_date();                              

        $content .= '<div class="latest-posts">';
        $content .= '<h3><a href='.$link.' target="_top">'.$title.' / '.$date. '</a></h3>';
        $content .= '<p class="excerpt">' .get_the_excerpt(). '</p>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    endwhile;

return $content;
}

add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es obtener la categoría del post actual para luego volver a pasarlo a la consulta:

```
//Modifico tu función para pasarle la anterior en las categorías.
function Last5posts()   {
//Guardamos la categoría del post actual.
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        $categories = $category->cat_name;
    }
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category_name' => $categories);                  
$last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) : 
    $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $date = get_the_date();                              
    $content .= '<div class="latest-posts">';
    $content .= '<h3><a href='.$link.' target="_top">'.$title.' / '.$date. '</a></h3>';
    $content .= '<p class="excerpt">' .get_the_excerpt(). '</p>';
    
    $content .= '</div>';
endwhile;

return $content;
}

add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

Comment: Hola Nando, muchas gracias por tu comentario. He probado la forma que comentas, pero no me funciona.

Comment: Que muestra el shortcode cuando lo insertas en el post?

Comment: @dvd_dev he editado y comprobado el código para que funcione, puedes probarlo.